# What happened to Stannis' fleet?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We know Stannis had a semi-large fleet when he traveled to the North and went past the wall to defeat the Wildling army.

After that, Jon Snow used the fleet to save the Wildlings at Hardhome. Stannis did say he expects his ships back because he will need them to conquer the rest of Westeros.

We all know how that turned out...

> Stannis' death is pretty much confirmed in season 6 when Brienne of Tarth tells Melisandre and Ser Davos that she executed Stannis personally.

Does the TV series hint in any way what happened to the fleet and its crew?

> The ships can’t be used to take back Winterfell so it’s normal that they would not be discussed during this period.

Still, such a fleet could be a powerful tool in the right hands.

Comment: I'm imagining Edd back at the wall, looking nervous and out of his depth still. Another Night's Watchman comes up to him. "Lord Commander, there are still 200 ships docked by Eastwatch and they need barnacles removing from the hull. The men are too busy rebuilding the wall". "I'm not Lord Commander" [awkward silence] "Oh, wait, I am, aren't I. FFS [picks up spade and bucket, trudges off sulkily]"

Comment: Was it not Sallador Saan's fleet, which Stannis had hired? It was in the books, the rest of Stannis' fleet burned in the wildfire on Blackwater. When Stannis ran out of money, Sallador ran away with his fleet. I think they carried some of that to the show.

Comment: @TLP wasn't that for the Battle of the Blackwater? Stannis got money again from the Iron Bank of Bravos, but did Ser Davos recruit Sallador again?

Comment: Wasn't there a whole sequence where Davos set about hiring his mercenary friend's fleet?  So... "his" (Stannis') fleet was the fleet he hired, not his original fleet that was nuked by Wildfyre, and when Stannis was routed and killed, they went on their merry way.

Answer (score 2):

Stannis paid money, borrowed from the Iron Bank, to pay for (hire) the crew of the ships, which included Davos' pirate friend, [Salladhor Saan](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Salladhor_Saan#Season_4).

Presumably, Stannis extended the payment for the mission to Hardhome, so when the money and leadership stopped ...

> seeing as Stannis, and therefore the Iron Bank's investment, died

... so did the fleet crew's services end (they got their money, but with no new money for new instruction, they left back home, presumably back to Essos).